# How can I get the Opengl version in SFML?

Tags: opengl, sfml

How can I get SFML to report the version of OpenGL that is being used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an OpenGL context with sf::RenderWindow and get the context settings with window.getSettings().

```
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600, 32), "SFML OpenGL");
sf::ContextSettings settings = window.getSettings();
std::cout << "OpenGL version:"<< settings.majorVersion << "." << settings.minorVersion << std::endl;
```